# CgridView ajax pagination

Tags: ajax, yii, pagination, cgridview

in my project i am using the cgridview inside a modal window. now i am facing the problem that when i select the pagination the page get reloaded. how can i load the grid view with ajax pagination. my ui code id given below...

```
<div id="pick-category-modal" title="Pick Category" class="popupinfoholder2">
    <div style="width:700px; height:auto;">
        <?php
        $widget = $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id' => 'response-grid',
            'dataProvider' => $pickdataset->pickSection(),
            'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/media/css/gridview.css',
            'summaryText' => '',
            'ajaxUpdate'=>true,
            'enablePagination' => true,
            'template' => '{items}',
            'pager' => array(
                'class' => 'LinkPager',
                'cssFile' => false,
                'header' => false,
                'firstPageLabel' => 'First',
                'prevPageLabel' => 'Previous',
                'nextPageLabel' => 'Next',
                'lastPageLabel' => 'Last',
            ),
            'columns' => array(
                .....................
                .....................
            ),));
        ?>
        <div class="grid-view-footer">
            <div class="paginationholder">
                <div id="pagination">
                    <?php $widget->renderPager(); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just testing this myself a moment ago, it appears that the pager kicked out with `renderPager()` does not work with the AJAX setting. The CGridView JavaScript only binds the AJAX to pagers inside the `<div>` rendered by the widget (`#response-grid` here), so it does not find and use your additional pager.

I just use the default pager that the CGridView renders at the bottom, and that works fine.

You could override the CGridView JS to fix this, or list it as an enhancement on the Yii bug tracker: http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/list

Comment: yes thats great i thought i will be do to my problem. @thaddeusmt i have one more doubt that is how can i bind and jquery click event to the image in the grid on completing the ajax update.

Comment: Which image are you trying to bind to?

Comment: just a chtml::image on every row having particluar id defined in alt tag

Comment: Hmm yeah I'd open another question about JS binds inside AJAXed CGrid rows, I'm not sure how that would work...